Is it preferable to work on Rosh Chodesh, or on Friday after Chatzchot HaYom?
Both Rosh Chodesh and Friday afternoon are characterized as times when work is permitted, but should be minimized. If one had to choose between the two, is there any halachic preference?

Work on Rosh chodesh is a stringency for the pious. Working late on Friday is a fence because you may lose track of time and commit a sin or forget something Shabbos related and ruin your Shabbos. The consequences of erring while working late on Friday are worse.
